# how to interface RS-422 to UART on my MCU?

Tags: microcontroller, uart, ethernet, rs422

I'm trying to interface RS-422 data to the UART on my MCU (TM4C1294ncpdt) to send it through its ethernet interface.

Can anyone help me with how to convert the RS-422 differential signal to be read by the UART?

circuit schematic or what components do i need to do this?

Comment: http://www.mouser.co.il/Semiconductors/Interface-ICs/RS-422-Interface-IC/_/N-45ly0/

Comment: a concise, non-redundant, easy to read, properly CaPitAlized question is much more important than additional "pls help". We're here to help each other, anyway, so no need to beg. Contribute to the community by asking good questions, and you should get help :)

Answer (score 3):

There are plenty of standard RS422-to-LVTTL conversion ICs available, so this should be straightforward.

Have a look at the following devices. Their data sheets should guide you on how to connect them to you UART's serial data output (TXD) and serial data input (RXD):

Maxim MAX3086

Texas Instruments family SN65HVD30 to SN65HVD35
Search TI website for data sheet 'SLLS665K'

Comment: What should I look for exactly in the datasheet ? Or would a RS422 to RS232 conversion ,and then rs232 to ttl be better?